# How to extract Quorum logs file from Azure Blockchain as Service

Tags: azure, quorum

I'm using Blockchain as Service on Azure (Quorum) for my PoC development. Is there a way to extract out the Quorum logs file from Azure? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Official docs, logs related to the Quorum ledger, or other important information such as attempted connections to the transaction nodes are made available through **Azure Log Analytics**. There are a variety of other metrics that provide insight into nodes' CPU, memory and storage usage, as well as helpful insights into blockchain network activity such as transactions and blocks mined, transaction queue depth, as well as active connections.

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/service/overview#monitoring-and-logging).